# disable click-through from bootstrap buttons behind a transparent header-div

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've a page with AngularJS and Bootstrap.
It's online in *(German and)* beta: [teacher.scool.cool](https://teacher.scool.cool)

- just use "test anmelden"
- switch to the next page in the menu

These page has a transparent fixed header div. No specific config for click-through.

```
.header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
    background: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
}
```

*I read about `pointer-events: none`.*

The buttons itself have also no specific config. They have the classes `btn btn-default btn-xs` for example. Inside is just a Glyphicon.

How can I disable the click-through possibility?

Comment: none of the buttons(`test anmelden`, `anmelden` and `Registrieren`) are working on chrome

Comment: I've also chrome, and I can click on "+" or "-"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a “click-through” issue – your buttons are just displayed *on top* of the header (because they come later in the document, and have `position:relative` set on the inner `span` elements.)

Simply adding a `z-index` for the header fixes that:

```
#master > #master-header {
  /* your other existing stuff here */
  z-index: 1;
}
```